# what is difference between code golfer and code fu?

Tags: discussion, code-golf

I am working around to stick with this site bit i am not able to understand what question should ask here and what exactly code golfers and code fu means and main difference I know this very silly and stupid answer.

Answer (score 2):

This site is a place to post-and-play games-and-challenges that are to be played or solved by writing programs and meet a number of additional requirements laid out in our FAQ (and unfortunately scattered around a number of meta posts...).

One of the big requirements that trip up new users is the "objective winning criteria" requirement. Code golf itself is a good example of that, at the winning entry is the *shortest* one. On the other hand "coolest" is not objective.

I'm not clear on why you think that code fu is an alternative to code golf, we don't use the phrase around here much, but it generally means the combination of deep knowledge and extensive experience that allows your code to have an intangible elegance to it.

Comment: The code-fu that can be measured is not the true code-fu.